# Permutations without repetitions (exclude repeated permutations)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The formula to calculate all permutations without repetitions of the set {1,2,3} is $\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ But how to calculate it if the set (or rather array in programming terms) includes repeated numbers {1,2,2,3,3} so that you don't add up same permutations?

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly you want. You talk of *permutations* but use the *combination* formula !

Comment: you are right, fixed

Comment: There is $r$ in your formula, but there isn't anything that seems to be $r$ in your question.

Comment: What about filtering only distinct values in the array and then count permutations? This seems to me like the fastest and the simplest solution. Otherwise you'd presumably have to count how many times each element is repeated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the set includes repeated terms it is actually not that different.

Take for example you want to find all different combinations of 'aabbcc'. What you would do is $\dfrac{6!}{2!2!2!}$, the numerator comes from the number of letters in 'aabbcc' and the denominator comes from all the repeated letters (we have 2 a's, 2 b's, and 2 c's).

You can do the same for numbers. To calculate the number of different permutations of {1,1,2,2,3,3}. It is just $\dfrac{6!}{2!2!2!}$, which is $\boxed{90}$ different permutations.

Answer (score 9):

First, to clear something up: the formula $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ is for a *combination* (i.e., the number of ways you can choose $r$ elements from a set of $n$ disregarding order), not a permutation. The formula for the number of permutations of a set with $n$ elements is simply $n!$.

Now, let's say we have your set $\{1,2_1,2_2,3_1,3_2\}$. It has $5$ elements, so there are $5!=120$ ways of permuting it $-$ or there would be, if we could tell every element apart. However, we don't actually want to consider two orderings different if they only differ by the swapping around of $2_1$ and $2_2$ and/or $3_1$ and $3_2$. So first let's say that we only care about the sequences where $2_1$ comes before $2_2$. Then we can throw away half of our 120 permutations (because every permutation that has $2_1$ before $2_2$ comes with a partner that is the same except with the two swapped), so we're down to $60$ permutations. We can use the same logic with $3_1$ and $3_2$ to cut our answer down to $30$ unique permutations, which is our final answer.

In general, if we have a set $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$, for each group of $k$ indistinguishable elements, we need to divide our initial result of $n!$ permutations by $k!$ (which you can justify using the same "ordering" argument as presented in the paragraph above).

Answer (score 4):

There is a standard formula to deal with such cases.

If n total objects have $k_1$ of one kind, $k_2$ of another, ......

number of permutations = $\dfrac{n!}{k_1!\cdot k_2!...}$

For your particular case, for instance, it would be $\dfrac{5!}{1!2!2!}$

The **1's** in the denominator can conveniently be left out. so $\dfrac{5!}{2!2!}$